# What are the recommended internet security measures to take?

Tags: windows, networking, security, internet

I have built a special-purpose server, the only purpose of this server is to download some data from a remote(internet) data feeder and then do some data processing.

The only internet connection I need is the connection to remote data feeder, the data feeder has a static IP address.

What are the best security measures I need to take to protect my computer from being infected by virus/trojans and being accessed illegaly from internet?

Its a Windows server, and there are firewall and anti-virus software installed, btw.

I am familiar with HPC applications, so I know some C/C++ stuff, just in case if needed.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure all accounts have strong passwords.  Change them regularly.
- Enable UAC and set it to the highest setting.
- Make sure your account that is used for day-to-day use on this system is NOT a member of the Administrators or Power Users group.  UAC will ask for your administrator password when you do something requiring elevation.
- Make sure no software is installed except what you need to accomplish your task.

  - Go to Programs and Features, then Turn Windows Features On and Off, and disable any Windows features you know you won't need.  Be careful as you might disable something needed for Windows to function correctly.
- Limit your use of Internet Explorer on the system.
- Make sure your antivirus updates are enabled and are updating regularly.
- Enable Windows Updates and make sure they are enabled.  Setup and configure a WSUS server if you want to review updates before applying.
- Configure the Windows Firewall to block all unsolicited incoming traffic.  Make an exception for Remote Desktop if you access this system remotely.
- If you do not remote into this system via the Internet or local network, disable Remote Desktop (Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Remote Settings).
- If you want to remote into this system via the Internet, you really do not want to have RDP accessible via the Internet.  Optimally you want to have it behind some sort of perimeter security, i.e. a software or hardware firewall and behind some sort of VPN or something that can authenticate your connection to your local network.  Contact a network or security professional to help you with this.

Comment: The last sentence is the key. If you want a really secure server, contact a professional. He's better at security than you.